# Use cache with multiple image in gitlab CICD

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd, docker-image

I am making a gitlab CI/CD pipeline that uses two different image.

One of them necessitate the installations of some package using `npm`. In order to avoid multiple-time installation I've added some cache.

Let's see this example :

```
stages:
    - build
    - quality

cache:
    paths:
        - node_modules/

build-one:
  image: node:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install <some package>

build-two:
  image: foo_image:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - some cmd

quality:
  image: node:latest
  stage: quality
  script:
    - <some cmd using the previously installed package>
```

The fact of having two different `docker images` forces me to specify it inside the job definition. So from my tests the cache isn't actually used and the command executed by the `quality` job will fail because the `package` isn't installed.

Is there a solution to this problem ?

Many thanks !
Kev'.

Comment: Are both the jobs running on the same runner.

Comment: your jobs shouldnt rely on the cache being populated. If you have more than one runner you are not assured that both jobs will run on the same runner. The cache is only persisted on the runner node. Instead run NPM in both jobs and NPM should be clever enough if the cache is there to know it doesnt need to download anything

Comment: I do not have control over the runners because I do not own the server, so should I assume I cannot be sure the runner will be the same between the jobs ? After few execution npm reinstalled the package without using the cache in the second stage every times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two cases

1. Same runner is being used to run all the jobs. In this case the way to specified cache should work fine.
2. Different runners are being used to run different jobs. So suppose `build` job runs with `runner 1` and `quality` jobs is running with `runner 2` so the cache will only be present in `runner 1`.

In order to make use of caching in `case 2` you will have to use [distributed caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#distributed-runners-caching).
Then `runner 1` will run the build job it will push the cache to s3 and `runner 2` will pull with cache during the quality job and then can use that.